# Reset value in another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I reset the second block (inches) to `0` when the first block (feet) is increased/decreased?

Would be great if you could kindly help out here. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.minus,.add').on('click', function() {
    var $qty = $(this).closest('.form-height').find('.qty'),
    currentVal = parseInt($qty.text()),
    isAdd = $(this).hasClass('add');
    !isNaN(currentVal) && $qty.text(
    isAdd ? ++currentVal : (currentVal > 0 ? --currentVal : currentVal)
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.form-height {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-height">
  <span class="qty">5</span> feet
  <img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/vpyob8urp/arrow-down.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/dae7dv3sl/arrow-up.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
<div class="form-height">
  <span class="qty">7</span> inches
  <img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/vpyob8urp/arrow-down.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/dae7dv3sl/arrow-up.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not using `input type=number`?

Comment: This isn't an editable field and hence in `<span>`. Read-only won't do too.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, please remember to pick an answer. If not, please comment on the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the 2 forms are not parent and children, they are sibligns. What you do with your code is to only handle only one of the 2 forms.

I recomend you to add differend (unique) classes to your qty or different (unique) ids. After that you can use selector like `$('.uniqueClass')` or $('#id') to select the span you want to edit.

Parent and child are that:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

not that:

```
<div class='sibling'></div>
<div class='sibling'></div>
```

Comment: I have removed the word "sibling/parent" from my question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `input type=number` and simply adding an `input` event listener to the feet input field, which sets the value of the inches field to `0`:

```js
feet.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  inches.value=0
})
```

```html
<label><input type="number" min=0 name="feet" id="feet" /> feet</label>
<label><input type="number" min=0 max=12 name="inches" id="inches" /> inches</label>
```

If you for whatever reason have to use `span` elements, here's how I'd do it:

```js
const pluses = [...document.querySelectorAll('.add')];
const minuses = [...document.querySelectorAll('.minus')];

for (const plus of pluses) {
  plus.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const qty = e.target.closest('.form-height').querySelector('.qty');
    console.log(qty.dataset);
    qty.dataset.qty = parseInt(qty.dataset.qty)+1 > 12 ? 12 : parseInt(qty.dataset.qty)+1;
    if (qty.classList.contains('feet')) {
      document.querySelector('.inches').dataset.qty = 0;
    }
    if (qty.classList.contains('inches')) {
      qty.dataset.qty = parseInt(qty.dataset.qty) > 12 ? 12 : parseInt(qty.dataset.qty);
    }
  })
}

for (const minus of minuses) {
  minus.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const qty = e.target.closest('.form-height').querySelector('.qty');
    qty.dataset.qty = parseInt(qty.dataset.qty)-1 < 0 ? 0 : parseInt(qty.dataset.qty)-1;
    if (qty.classList.contains('feet')) {
      document.querySelector('.inches').dataset.qty = 0;
    }
  })
}
```

```css
[data-qty]::before {
  content: attr(data-qty);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-height">
  <span class="qty feet" data-qty="5"></span> feet
  <img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/vpyob8urp/arrow-down.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/dae7dv3sl/arrow-up.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />
</div>
<div class="form-height">
  <span class="qty inches" data-qty="7"></span> inches
  <img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/vpyob8urp/arrow-down.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/dae7dv3sl/arrow-up.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:-

```
<h5>Height</h5>
<div class="form-height">
  <span class="qty">5</span> feet
  <img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/vpyob8urp/arrow-down.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/dae7dv3sl/arrow-up.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
<div class="form-height">
  <span class="qty" id="inches">7</span> inches
  <img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/vpyob8urp/arrow-down.png" id="minus2" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add2" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/dae7dv3sl/arrow-up.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
```

jQuery:-

```
$(function() {
  $('.minus,.add').on('click', function(e) {
  var targetId = e.currentTarget.id;
  if(targetId == 'add1' || targetId == 'minus1'){
  $('#inches').text(0);
  }
  if(targetId == 'add2' &&  parseInt($('#inches').text()) >= 7){
   alert('maximum height reached');
   return false;
  }
    var $qty = $(this).closest('.form-height').find('.qty'),
    currentVal = parseInt($qty.text()),
    isAdd = $(this).hasClass('add');
    !isNaN(currentVal) && $qty.text(
    isAdd ? ++currentVal : (currentVal > 0 ? --currentVal : currentVal)
    );
  });
});
```

this is the working jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/677928/